# Add all file name from directory with specific file format to Contextmenu and get file path when click

Tags: vb.net, winforms, contextmenu

i want to add all file name in directory to contextmenu..

i can add all file name from directory to listview, but when I want to add to the ContextMenu with the same code , I get an error .. that essentially says " can not be converted to toolstrip items " , " Can not be converted to string "

```
Public App_Path As String = Application.StartupPath

Dim di As New IO.DirectoryInfo(App_Path & "/Article/Profile/Egg/")
Dim diar1 As IO.FileInfo() = di.GetFiles()
Dim dra As IO.FileInfo
For Each dra In diar1
    'Listview1.Items.Add(dra)  ----> this is working
    ContextMenu.Items.Add(dra)  '----> this is not working
Next
```

sorry for my bad english..

Comment: `dra` is a `FileInfo` object, you probably want one of the properties like `dra.FullName` for the text.  And probably need to add a contextmenu type item to it, using that filename as the text.  you cant just add any old object to any old thing you want.

Comment: great.. its working but i use "dra.Name" not "dra.Fullname" but the file format is still visible " Filename.rtf " how to remove the .rtf and how do I click any item , the location of the file appears on the label.

Comment: then, next look into `System.Io.Path`

Comment: I got rid of the file format using System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension ( dra.Name ) , one last question unanswered , how when I click on an item in the ContextMenu , the location of the file appears on the label ? might be able to give me a little hint..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wire up the ToolStripItem with AddHandler as you create each one.  Something like:

```
Public Class Form1

    Public App_Path As String = Application.StartupPath

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim di As New IO.DirectoryInfo(App_Path & "/Article/Profile/Egg/")
        For Each dra As IO.FileInfo In di.GetFiles
            Dim TSI As ToolStripItem = ContextMenuStrip1.Items.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(dra.FullName))
            TSI.Tag = dra.FullName
            AddHandler TSI.Click, AddressOf TSI_Click
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub TSI_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim TSI As ToolStripItem = CType(sender, ToolStripItem)
        Label1.Text = TSI.Tag
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: i dont know why but MenuItems is not member of System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenuStrip..

Comment: You're right.  It's not.  Your question text and code suggested you're using a ContextMenu, not a ContextMenuStrip.  These are two completely different controls!

Comment: Code updated to demonstrate the ContextMenuStrip with the ToolStripItem, instead of the ContextMenu with the MenuItem.